# Send SMS without confirm in VS 2015 VB Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-phone-8

Im working on a Windows Phone 8.1 App in Visual Studio

I want to a SMS message to a predefined number with set message whenuser presses a button.

So the message need to be sent in the background.

Is this possible?

All I got so far is:

```
Dim message As New Chat.ChatMessage
message.Recipients.Add("07867660552")
message.Body = "This is a text message from an riaz!"
Await Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(message)
```

Answer (score -1):

No, only mobile operators have this possibility for security reason.